# Receiving [Object Object] from jQuery .text()

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table made from divs, and i'm trying to add the table header content to a data attribute on each cell to be used for mobile devices.

However my table shows [Object Object] after each cell. I'm not the most efficiant with jQuery so any help will be appreciated.

```js
    var $table_header = $('.tech-specs header.table-row .table-cell');
    var $table_cell = $('.tech-specs div.table-row .table-cell');
    $table_cell.text(function() {
      var i = $(this).index();
      return $(this).text() + $(this).attr('data-title', $table_header.eq(i).text());
    });
```

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.table-row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
.table-row > * {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 20px 8px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
header.table-row {
    background: #37bb1f;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table tech-specs five-cells">
  <header class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Cloud Servers</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Minimum Hypervisor spec</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Storage</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Network</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Datacenters</div>
  </header>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">1 IPv4 addresses</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Intel Xeon minimum 8 core</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Enterprise grade</div>
    <div class="table-cell">1Gbit for each HyperVisor</div>
    <div class="table-cell">UPS and Generator Backed</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Auto failover</div>
    <div class="table-cell">ECC registered RAM</div>
    <div class="table-cell">HP Powered</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Global Network with over 200Gbit of capacity</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Managed by in-house staff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the attribute you should use [`.attr( attributeName, function )`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

```
$table_cell.attr('data-title', function() {
  var i = $(this).index();
  return $table_header.eq(i).text();
});
```

`$(this).attr('data-title', $table_header.eq(i).text())` returns jQuery object and you are appending thus you are getting `[Object Object]`

```
$table_cell.text(function() {
  var i = $(this).index();
  var text = $table_header.eq(i).text(); //Get the text
  $(this).attr('data-title', text); //set it as attribute value 
  return $(this).text() + text;
});
```

```js
var $table_header = $('.tech-specs header.table-row .table-cell');
var $table_cell = $('.tech-specs div.table-row .table-cell');
$table_cell.text(function() {
  var i = $(this).index();
  var text = $table_header.eq(i).text()
  $(this).attr('data-title', text);
  return $(this).text() + text;
});
```

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-row > * {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 20px 8px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header.table-row {
  background: #37bb1f;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table tech-specs five-cells">
  <header class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Cloud Servers</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Minimum Hypervisor spec</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Storage</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Network</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Datacenters</div>
  </header>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">1 IPv4 addresses</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Intel Xeon minimum 8 core</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Enterprise grade</div>
    <div class="table-cell">1Gbit for each HyperVisor</div>
    <div class="table-cell">UPS and Generator Backed</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Auto failover</div>
    <div class="table-cell">ECC registered RAM</div>
    <div class="table-cell">HP Powered</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Global Network with over 200Gbit of capacity</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Managed by in-house staff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, `$table_cell.attr('data-title', function() {` makes much more sense as the text is staying as is... thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In table cell you are not trying changing the text as well. What you need is to set an attribute to that div. So you don't have to return any data. Just set the attribute like below:

```js
var $table_header = $('.tech-specs header.table-row .table-cell');
    var $table_cell = $('.tech-specs div.table-row .table-cell');
    $table_cell.text(function() {
      var i = $(this).index();
      $(this).attr('data-title', $table_header.eq(i).text());
      //return $(this).text() + $(this).attr('data-title', $table_header.eq(i).text());
    });
```

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.table-row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
.table-row > * {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 20px 8px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
header.table-row {
    background: #37bb1f;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table tech-specs five-cells">
  <header class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Cloud Servers</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Minimum Hypervisor spec</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Storage</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Network</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Datacenters</div>
  </header>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">1 IPv4 addresses</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Intel Xeon minimum 8 core</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Enterprise grade</div>
    <div class="table-cell">1Gbit for each HyperVisor</div>
    <div class="table-cell">UPS and Generator Backed</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Auto failover</div>
    <div class="table-cell">ECC registered RAM</div>
    <div class="table-cell">HP Powered</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Global Network with over 200Gbit of capacity</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Managed by in-house staff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```